# Migrating from ionic-select-searchable to ionic-selectable throws an issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've been testing the ionic-selectable using an array to select and search options in as ionic-select-searchable has been deprecated. However, I get an issue that when selecting options with the new ionic-selectable, all are selected instead of individual items and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my home.html code:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Ionic Selectable</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Diagnosis</ion-label>
    <ionic-selectable
      item-content
      [(ngModel)]="diagnosis"
      itemValueField="id"
      itemTextField="name"
      [items]="diagnoses"
      [canSearch]="true"
      (onChange)="diagnosisChange($event)">
    </ionic-selectable>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

My home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicSelectableComponent } from 'ionic-selectable';
import { DiagnosisService } from '../../services';
import { Diagnosis } from '../../types';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  diagnoses: Diagnosis[];
  diagnosis: Diagnosis;

  constructor(
    private diagnosisService: DiagnosisService
  ) {
    this.diagnoses = this.diagnosisService.getDiagnoses();
  }

  diagnosisChange(event: {
    component: IonicSelectableComponent,
    value: any
  }) {
    console.log('diagnosis:', event.value);
  }
}
```

My diagnosis.services.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Diagnosis } from '../types';

@Injectable()
export class DiagnosisService {
  private diagnoses: Diagnosis[] = [
      {name: 'Hypothyroidism' },
      {name: 'Hyperthyroidism' },
      {name: 'Diabetes Type 1' },
      {name: 'Diabetes Type 2' }];

  getDiagnoses(page?: number, size?: number): Diagnosis[] {
    let diagnoses = [];

      this.diagnoses.forEach(diagnosis => {
        diagnoses.push(diagnosis);
      });

    if (page && size) {
      diagnoses = diagnoses.slice((page - 1) * size, ((page - 1) * size) + size);
    }

    return diagnoses;
  }
}
```

I've essentially created a stackblitz here and you can see what error I'm experiencing:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-on-search-upikeg

Here's the plunker that works with the older ionic-select-searchable:
http://plnkr.co/edit/3xxNuMSIqvli8Djv8F1A?p=preview

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're telling that component to use the `id` to identify each option:

```
<ionic-selectable
  item-content
  [(ngModel)]="diagnosis"
  itemValueField="id" <!-- Here! -->
  itemTextField="name"
  [items]="diagnoses"
  [canSearch]="true"
  (onChange)="diagnosisChange($event)">
</ionic-selectable>
```

but your model doesn't have an `id`. So I'd recommend to add an `id` field to each entity and use it as the `itemValueField`, or if you don't want to add the id, you can use the `name` (only if each item has a different name).

This is a **[working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-on-search-3kg1k9)** for example if you modify the component to use the `name` property instead of the `id` in the `itemValueField`:

```
<ionic-selectable
  item-content
  [(ngModel)]="diagnosis"
  itemValueField="name" <!-- Here! -->
  itemTextField="name"
  [items]="diagnoses"
  [canSearch]="true"
  (onChange)="diagnosisChange($event)">
</ionic-selectable>
```